# Kotlin - Crash on Nested AlertDialog for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin, multiple-alert-dialogs

FYI I'm starting to learn Kotlin & have previous experience with Python and PyQT.

Goal is to have a for loop iterate a certain amount of times based on user input. Each iteration of the for loop should bring up an alert dialog that saves the text input to ArrayList.

Currently, an alert dialog shows asking for the site name. After entering the name and tapping 'Ok' an alert dialog shows asking for the amount of buildings at the site. That input gets saved as an integer used as the for loop limit. This is when the app crashes. The alert dialog asking for the site name never shows. Any suggestions?

```
btn_new_site.setOnClickListener { view ->
        //maybe convert this to seperate .kt and import in.
        //change to one builder & inflater & just change parameters?

        //ask for site name
        val site_builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val site_inflater = layoutInflater
        site_builder.setTitle("Site Name")
        val dialogLayout = site_inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_site_name, null)
        val site_name  = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.site_name)
        site_builder.setView(dialogLayout)
        site_builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, i ->
            sites.add(site_name.text.toString())
            //ask for amount of buildings at site
            val amt_building_builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val amt_building_inflater = layoutInflater
            amt_building_builder.setTitle("How many buildings?")
            val dialogLayout = amt_building_inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_site_amt_buildings, null)
            val site_amt_buildings  = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.site_amt_buildings)
            amt_building_builder.setView(dialogLayout)
            amt_building_builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, i ->
                val amtBuildings = site_amt_buildings.text.toString()
                val building_amt = amtBuildings.toInt()

                //ask for building names
                val building_name_builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                val buiding_name_inflater = layoutInflater
                building_name_builder.setTitle("Building Name")
                val dialogLayout = buiding_name_inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_building_name, null)
                val building_name  = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.building_name)
                building_name_builder.setView(dialogLayout)
                building_name_builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, i ->
                    //add to list of buildings for x site here
                }

                //ask for building names here
                for ( buildings in 1..building_amt) building_name_builder.show()
            }
            amt_building_builder.show()
        }

        site_builder.show()

    }


}
```

No errors show when compiling. Just warning about some parameters never being used.

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: That error comes up at the for loop line

Comment: On first iteration in for-loop the builder adds the `dialogLayout` view to the `AlertDialog`. On second iteration it tries to do that again but the error occurs because `dialogLayout` already has a parent. You should for each iteration of the loop inflate a new `dialogLayout` and set it as view in the builder before calling `show()`.